# AttributeError: module 'vpython' has no attribute 'pca_results'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```
# Generate PCA results plot
pca_results = vs.pca_results(good_data, pca)
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-57043f6481bb> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Generate PCA results plot
----> 2 pca_results = vs.pca_results(good_data, pca)

AttributeError: module 'vpython' has no attribute 'pca_results'
```

I am working in Google Colab. I do not know why I receive this error.

Comment: Which library is it? Does it have a doc?

Comment: https://github.com/prakhardogra921/Clustering-Analysis-on-customers-of-a-wholesale-distributor/blob/master/customer_segments.ipynb

Comment: where is your import of `visuals` or definition of `vs`

Comment: I import `visuals` on top of command as `import visuals as vs`

Comment: so what is `vpython` ?

Comment: I suspect some namespace polution